# for文を使用して連続的にファイルを読み込みたい

Tags: python, pandas

pandasの `read_text_file = pd.read_csv()` を使用してテキストファイルを読み取っているのですが、ファイルが数百あるので連続的にfor文を使用して文中でテキストファイル名を変更して自動化できないかと考えています。

そこで、下記のコードのように試作として `for i in range(1, 4):` で `i` という変数を1～3まで連続的に変化させて、その次の行にある `name="No"+str(i)+".txt"` でファイル名にしていますが、以下のエラーが発生してしまいました。

この場合の解消法を教えていただけたらと思います。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

**ソースコード:**

```
pip install plotly==5.10.0  #グラフ描画用ライブラリのインストール

import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

for i in range(1, 4):
  name = "No" + str(i) + ".txt"
  read_text_file = pd.read_csv (name)          # テキストファイルの読み込み
  name1 = "No" + str(i) + ".csv"
  read_text_file.to_csv (name1, index=None)     # テキストファイルをcsvにコンバート

  df = pd.read_csv(name1, header=None, sep="\s+")  # csvをDataFrameに代入する、今回の場合はcsvにheaderがないのでNoneを指定

  labels =  ["TIME", "CH1", "CH2", "CH3", "CH4"]                    # 辞書用に列名のリストを作成しておく
  labels_dict = {num: label for num, label in enumerate(labels)}    # csvのheaderがないのでリストから辞書を作成しておく
  df = df.rename(columns = labels_dict)                             # DataFrameのカラム名を変更
  name2 = "No" + str(i) + "_comp.csv"
  # カラム名を追加したデータフレームをcsvファイルとして保存する。
  df.to_csv(name2, index=False)

  df = pd.read_csv(name2)    # カラム名を追加したcsvを読み込み
  name3 = "No" + str(i) + "_comptest.csv"
  new_file2 = "name3"      # 後で別名のcsvを出力するために定義

  df["THL"] = ((((df["CH1"] - 988) + (df["CH3"] - 988) + (df["CH2"] - 988) + (df["CH4"] - 988)) / 4)/ 820)*100
  #df["THL"] = ((((df["CH1"] - 1252) + (df["CH3"] - 1252) + (df["CH2"] - 1252) + (df["CH4"] - 1252)) / 4)/ 556)*100        # 既存のcsvの1列から4列の数値で計算した結果で新しい列を作成
  df["RUD"] = ((((df["CH2"] - 988) + (df["CH4"] - 988) - ((df["CH1"] - 988) + (df["CH3"] - 988))) / 2) / 1544)*100 
  df["ELE"] = ((((df["CH2"] - 988) + (df["CH1"] - 988) - ((df["CH4"] - 988) + (df["CH3"] - 988))) / 2) / 1544)*100
  df["AIL"] = ((((df["CH2"] - 988) + (df["CH3"] - 988) - ((df["CH1"] - 988) + (df["CH4"] - 988))) / 2) / 1544)*100

  df.to_csv(new_file2,index=False)    # 新しい列を追加したcsvを別名で出力、indexをFalseにすることで上書きを防ぐ

  df = pd.read_csv(name3, index_col=0)   # 後で確認
  data = [
          go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['THL'], name='THL', line=dict(color="#ea553a")),  # グラフのチャートの参照するDataFrameと名前を指定
          ]

  name4 = "飛行試験No" + str(i) + "送信機の操作量の変位(20221027)"
  name5 = "操作量のお試しNo" + str(i) + ".html"
  layout = go.Layout(                                          # グラフのレイアウトの設定
                      title= name4,
                      xaxis={'title': '時間 [ms]'},
                      yaxis={'title': '操作量 [%]'},
                      font={'size': 18},
                      width=1000,
                      height=600
                      )         

  fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

  fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor="white")
  fig.update_xaxes(linecolor='black', gridcolor='white',mirror=True)
  fig.update_yaxes(linecolor='black', gridcolor='white',mirror=True)
  fig.update_yaxes(range = [0,100])  

  fig.write_html(name5)   # 出力するグラフ用ファイルの命名
  plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

Comment: 画面での確認ですが `name1 = "No" + str(i) + ",csv"` の行の `csv` の前がカンマだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。打ち間違えてました。

Comment: しかし、別のエラーが発生しました

Comment: エラー情報は，（28行目で）「演算子 '-' の被演算子（この場合両側）が'str'と'int'なので型が不適合」と読めます。

Comment: この場合、int()でstr型をint型に変換すればよろしいのでしょうか？初心者で知識が不足しているため教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2):

適当に入力データを作っての検討では，下記の2カ所の修正でエラーは出なくなりました。

```
  # df = pd.read_csv(name1, header=None, sep=r"\s+")
  df = pd.read_csv(name1, header=None)
```

```
  # new_file2 = "name3"
  new_file2 = name3
```

また，グラフについては（ブラウザに）タイトルと軸と折れ線が表示され，入力データを変化させると形状も変化します。

なお，細かい話ですが下記のように書き換えることができます。

```
  # labels_dict = {num: label for num, label in enumerate(labels)}
  labels_dict = dict(enumerate(labels))
```